# Quickest way to submit form data to Salesforce

Tags: integration

I have just started my Salesforce trial. I use Wordpress form plugin (visual form builder pro) on my website. What would be the quickest way to integrate submissions from this form to my Salesforce lists?

I was hoping to be able to submit data via jQuery and hidden fields but couldn't find any form options.

After doing some more research, I found [WP-VFBP-2-SF](https://github.com/mattwithoos/WP-VFBP-2-SF/blob/master/wpvfbp2sf.php) but it requires web2lead which I can not locate in my Salesforce admin area.

Comment: What salesforce edition are you using ? You may want to give us more details, this question is pretty hard to solve right now.

Comment: It's hard to tell. It doesn't specify if it's a developer version or not. All I know is that I am using SalesforceIQ. We just made a payment and on the billing page, I can see that we have got Growth plan.

Answer (score 1):

I use a plugin called gravity forms .

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cl_about.htm

Gravity forms provide you built in connector to connect wordpress and SFDC

https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-salesforce/screenshots/

The coolest thing is you can connect wordpress to custom objects and custom fields

Comment: Yes, gravityform looks great but we use visual form builder pro. :( I should probably add this information.

Comment: ah nps. I will leave the info here so it helps someone :)

Comment: I was just wondering if web2lead is available in the trial version. The script I have discussed above requires web2lead.

Comment: Yes you can enable web to lead in developer edition .